# Django QuerySet filter on inverse relationship

Tags: django

Really struggling with this one and could appreciate some help. I have the following model...

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='booking', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    check_out_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.property}"

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

But when I run the following (below) to retrieve property bookings with a date equal to 2021-05-14, instead of just the bookings with a check_in_date of 2021-05-14 being returned, all the bookings for each property are returned even if they don't have a check_in_date of 2021-05-14

```
Property.objects.filter(booking__check_in_date='2021-05-14')
```

Probably something really simple, but I'm new to Django have been stuck on this all morning and could appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: You filter the `Property`s in the `QuerySet`, but if you access `some_property.booking.all()` will not be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need something like this:

```
bookings = Booking.objects.filter(check_in_date='2021-05-14')
properties = [booking.property for booking in bookings]
```

Because property is available on a Booking object and you're initally filtering bookings.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. This has helped  immensely.

Answer (score 1):

to filter DateFields in Django you must convert the date string to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime


check_in_date = datetime.strptime('2021-05-14',  '%Y-%m-%d')
properties = Property.objects.filter(booking__check_in_date=check_in_date)
```